# Will my application overload if i use too many panels?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, drawing

I am developing an application and i need small squares on the board that will change color on different value selected.

So i am planning to use `Panels` and simply change their back ground color this will get my issue solved. 
So in total their might be `10-15` panels on the one `Form`

What i want to know .Is this bad approach?

As i do not see any other control than this to fill my need, i am using Vs 2010.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 10 to 15 panels should be no problem at all even for slower devices (eg. mobile devices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to provide a colored square, you could use classes from [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx) that provides shapes like circles, rectangles, etc. For sample:

Import the namespace

```
using System.Drawing;
```

And try a code like this:

```
SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();

formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));

myBrush.Dispose();
formGraphics.Dispose();
```

### See Also

- [How to: Draw a Filled Rectangle on a Windows Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztxk24yx(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Code: Drawing Graphics on a Windows Form (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287594(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: This is possible in .Net too haha, but you could use panels without problem. I think for shapes, this is more appropriate. You also could save a picture with the `Bitmap` class.

Comment: Yup you are rite i should use the right tool for the rite thing , i need shapes so i will draw them . Thank you

Comment: Before/when implementing this solution please do learn about the Winforms graphics paradigm! IOW: Do not do it like that!!! This is completely wrong. The idea to draw the stuff you want to see it right and much better than creating a Panels (ie. a new Window) for each square is correct. But doing it this way (by drawing with a `this.CreateGraphics()`  is non-persistent and wrong. All your drawing needs to happen/be triggered from a Paint event!

Comment: @TaW A bit late but i will read it to understand more , thank you

Comment: Sure. Come back if you need more advice or run into problems. .